# Determining the equation of $g(x)$ given intersecting points via another function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, quadratics, quadratic-forms

Here's the problem:

[image]

I know this is a system of quadratic-quadratic equations. My attempt was to convert the equation of $f(x)$ into the form $f(x) = a(x - p)^2 + q$, making the $a$ negative to determine the equation of $g(x)$.

$f(x) = (x^2 - 6x) +5$

$f(x) = (x^2 - 6x + (- \frac{6}{2})^2 - (- \frac{6}{2})^2) + 5$

$f(x) = (x^2 - 6x + 9) - 9 + 5$

$f(x) = (x - 3)^2 - 4$

-

$f(x) = -(x - 3)^2 - 4$

I then plugged in the points into the equation, but they weren't solutions so I know I approached this problem wrong.

The textbook answer is $g(x) = -(x - 6)^2 + 13$, how should I get this vertex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track when you made the $a$ negative. Since the question says $f(x)$ is congruent to $g(x)$, you know that the $a$'s in both equations will only differ in sign.

As for $p$ and $q$, you have two points that $g(x)$ passes through and two unknowns in the equation. Looks like a system of equations should do the trick. Can you take it from here?

Comment: To find $p$ and $q$, I can just plug in the two points and make a system of equations. I see.

Comment: Yep, that's it!

Comment: I tried using the process of elimination approach, but i'm stuck since i always worked with standard form and system of quadratics in vertex form is new to me. How should i do this?

Comment: Plug in $a=-1$ and values of $x$ and $y$ . You will get two equations :             
                                                   $(p-2)^2$$-$ $q$= $3$ and $(p-7)^2$$-$ $q$=$-$$12$ . Subtract these equations to eliminate $q$ and then use the identity $(a^2-b^2)$ = $(a-b)*(a+b)$. You should get $p=6$ .